# How to make default number of items selected in React bootstrap table pagination

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap table in my application, I am also using the pagination of bootstrap table. By default 10 is selected in the application and when I select the number of items let's say 25, the respective number of items appear.

[image: Pagination Image]

But if I then change the route (after component unmount) by clicking somewhere else and again come back, it looses its state and again by default 10 number of items gets selected, but the 25 from the dropdown should be selected as before unmount it was 25.

my options which I am passing to `paginationFactory()` function

```
const options = {
      paginationSize: 3,
      showTotal: true,
      paginationTotalRenderer: customTotal,
      disablePageTitle: true,
      sizePerPageList: [{
        text: '10', value: 10
      }, {
        text: '25', value: 25
      }, {
        text: '50', value: 50
      }, {
        text: 'All', value: this.state.toggleList.length
      }],
      onSizePerPageChange: this.onPageSizeChange
    };
```

I am using the function `onSizePerPageChange` to get the selected number of items when size is changed, I have also stored the value in redux store and whenever we get back to the component in the props I am receiving that previously selected value, but how to make that value by default selected in that pagination dropdown.
Please help me.

JSX for bootstrap table

```
<BootstrapTable
     keyField="id"
     data={currentToggleList}
     columns={columns}
     pagination={paginationFactory(options)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, in the options need to pass one more property `sizePerPage` which will by default provide the number of items per page.

```
const options = {
      paginationSize: 3,
      showTotal: true,
      paginationTotalRenderer: customTotal,
      disablePageTitle: true,
      sizePerPageList: [{
        text: '10', value: 10
      }, {
        text: '25', value: 25
      }, {
        text: '50', value: 50
      }, {
        text: 'All', value: this.state.toggleList.length
      }],
      onSizePerPageChange: this.onPageSizeChange,
      sizePerPage: this.state.sizePerPage               // Added new property
    };
```